# Cache implementation method

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I want to save as cache as UserDefaults.
But,

This is `signupButtonTapped`:

```
@IBAction private func signUpButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    KRProgressHUD.show(withMessage: "loading")
    Authentication.signUp(
        name: nameTextField.text!, // "new"
        email: emailTextField.text!, // "new"
        password: passwordTextField.text!, // "new"
        image: selectedImage,
    onSuccess: {
        KRProgressHUD.dismiss()
        API.User.getCurrentUser { (user) in
            CurrentUser.shared.synchronize(user: user)
        }
        self.presentViewController()
    }) { (error) in
        KRProgressHUD.showError(withMessage: "\(error!)")
    }
}
```

this is `CurrentUser` class:

```
import Foundation

final class CurrentUser: User {

// Get
static let shared: CurrentUser = {
    let user = CurrentUser()
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    user.userID = userDefaults.string(forKey: userID_field)
    user.name = userDefaults.string(forKey: name_field)
    user.email = userDefaults.string(forKey: email_field)
    return user
}()

// Save
func synchronize(user: user) {
    print(user.name, user.userID, user.email)  // "new", "new", "new"
// <<<< BREAKPOINT

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(user.userID, forKey: userID_field)
    userDefaults.set(user.name, forKey: name_field)
    userDefaults.set(user.email, forKey: email_field)

    print(userDefaults.string(forKey: name_field), userDefaults.string(forKey: userID_field), userDefaults.string(forKey: email_field)) // "new", "new", "new"
    print(CurrentUser.shared.name, CurrentUser.shared.userID, CurrentUser.shared.email) // "old", "old", "old"
// <<<< BREAKPOINT
}
```

I want the last `print(CurrentUser.shared.ooo)` function to be "new", "new", "new".

However, the old value "old" is displayed instead.

What is wrong with my cache implementation?

Comment: I believe you are re-saving old values i.e `pillar.xxx`, rather you should save `user.xxx` the new values

Comment: @kathayatnk Thank you comment!　Sorry, I made a typo. But even if i change it to user.xxx, i get the same result

Comment: Is it also typo where you are using ‘pillar.xxx = xxx’, you are not assigning the values from cache to user in your shared current user property

Comment: @kathayatnk user.name = userDefaults.string(forKey: name_field) 　I intend to assign it to shared current user property with this code, but is not it OK with this?

Comment: There is problem because of static property which is computed only ones. So if I may suggest I would go with something like my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using static instance `shared` that property will only hold the first value. You need to change your strategy to something else, because once your app is launched the computed property won't compute again and thus won't fetch data from userdefaults.

You see when you save your new data and then quit and launch your app again it should display the expected result, but since you are trying to get the data when your app is launched it will obviously display the previously stored one. A simple solution would be to not user shared instance for this, you could do something like following:

```
//Put the currentUser in User class

class User {
   var userID = ""
   var name = ""
   var email = ""

  class var current: User {
       let user = User()
       let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
       user.email = defaults.string(forKey: email_field) ?? ""  //this can be nil if no data
       user.userID = defaults.string(forKey: userID_field) ?? ""
       user.name = defaults.string(forKey: name_field) ?? ""
       return user
  }

  func synchronize() {

       let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
       userDefaults.set(self.userID, forKey: userID_field)
       userDefaults.set(self.name, forKey: name_field)
       userDefaults.set(self.email, forKey: email_field)

       print(userDefaults.string(forKey: name_field), userDefaults.string(forKey: userID_field), userDefaults.string(forKey: email_field))
      print(User.current.name, User.current.userID, User.current.email)
  }

}
```

Now you can perform your operations. Like so

```
let newUser = User()
newUser.userID = "123"
....

newUser.synchronize() //save 


//When you need current user 

 User.current
```

Comment: I am sorry to reply late. Thank you!　As you say, I've decided to put class var current in the User